# Ruby conditional assignment with a hash

Tags: ruby

anyone care to explain what this syntax means in Ruby?

```
class Animal
  def name_category
    @animals ||={}
  end
end
```

Also, is there a way for setting up object variable without using attr_accessor, attr_reader, attr_writer or def initialize?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "setting up object variable"?

Comment: by object variable, I mean the variable that is using @ sigil. Sorry I just started to learn ruby, I didn't know that it was the wrong term

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure I understood. In Ruby, prepending a variable name with with `@` declares it an instance variable, and it's initialized to `nil` unless assigned to something else.

Comment: The `attr_` methods are just a shorthand way of declaring setters and getters for your instance variables, so if you just have `attr_accessor :name` without assigning anything to `@name` anywhere inside of your class definition, `#name` will just return `nil` unless you assign it something with `#name=`.

Answer (score 6):

`||=` is Ruby's conditional assignment operator. `a ||= b` can usually be taken as short for

```
a || (a = b)
```

That is, `a` is assigned `b` if `a` is `nil` or `false` (i.e., `a = b` conditional on the falsiness of `a`).

The operator exploits a property of the way `||` is evaluated. Namely, that the right-hand operand of `||` is not evaluated unless the left-hand one is truthy (i.e., not `false` or `nil`). This is known as [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In your case, unless `@animals` already possesses a non-falsy value, it will be bound to an empty hash `{}`.

It's important to note that despite the superficial similarity of `||=` to operators like `+=` and `-=`, `a ||= b` is not equivalent to `a = a || b`.

For a counterexample, take `a = Hash.new(true)`. Then:

```
a[:key] ||= :value
#=> true
a
#=> {}
```

Compare with

```
a[:key] = a[:key] || :value
#=> true

a
#=> {:key=>true}
```

However, strictly speaking `a ||= b` is also not equivalent to `a || a = b`. If `a` is undefined, then

```
>> a || a = false
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

but

```
>> a ||= false
#=> false
```

and

```
>> a = a || false
#=> false
```

Something to keep in mind.

So it’s more accurate, if less syntactically elegant, to say that `a ||= b` is equivalent to

```
(defined?(a) && a) ? a : a = b
```

Here's a good post on [Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) elaborating on this point further.

Comment: You mean `a = a || b`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This short circuiting is a new subject to me! I'll look for the post and article!

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to (really long hand unpretty form):

```
if @animal == nil  # (falsey really, but nil is what we're looking for here)
  @animal = {}
end
return @animal
```

Basically: return @animal, unless it's not initialized in which case initialized it to {} before return it.

You could also write it as:

```
@animal = {} unless @animal
return @animal
```

Or

```
@animal ||= {}
return @animal
```

But then @animal ||= {} evaluates to @animal anyway, and you can skip the return

Comment: `if !@animal` is more accurate — it will assign if the value is nil **or false** (i.e. the "falsy" values).